# Globalize.js - cldr.once is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-globalize, javascript-globalize

I'm using Globalize.js script in my app to work with locales. All works well, except currency formating. When I use **Globalize.currencyFormatter(currency)**, I'm getting this error

> TypeError: cldr.once is not a function

I don't know where should I get "once" function. I've searched in cldr library (latest version 5.0) and don't see once function. Where it suppose to get from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Globalize.js has a dependency to the CLDR low level manipulation tool [cldr.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cldrjs). `once` is its method for adding event listeners. Make sure you have loaded `cldr.js` on the page or included it as part of your build.

Answer (score 4):

cldr.once is part of a supplemental library `cldr/event.js` found in the `dist` folder of cldr [repository](https://github.com/rxaviers/cldrjs/releases)